# Компьютер не заряжается полностью. Debian

Tags: debian

Здравствуйте!Возникла такая проблема. Ноутбук перестал заряжаться полностью. Каждый раз останавливается примерно на 45%. Есть какие-то решения этой проблемы, не связанные с заменой аккумулятора?

Comment: Вы не по теме. Для таких целей есть отдельные разделы на StackExchange. Например, SuperUser.

Comment: Каких-нибудь настроек там нет? Когда у меня был нетбук, он при первом включении спросил что-то типа: "если вы хотите продлить срок службы аккумулятора при преимущественном использовании от сети, то давайте я буду заряжать его только на 80%".

Comment: @Qwerty, кажется, нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наверно только сравнив её реальную емкость

```
cat cacatys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_full
```

С той что должна быть

```
cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_full_design
```

Хотя многие производители дают возможность ограничить заряд батареи до 80% или около того, чтобы продлить службу батареи. Но это точно не Ваш случай.

Comment: Значения одинаковые